# Is there any way to know where is used a movieclip?

Tags: flash

I have a huge library in Flash CS5. Sometimes, I need to know in which place is used a movieclip (scene, inside another movieclip..).

Has Flash any options to know that?

Txs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every displayobject has a parent property that stores exactly what you need to know. Just chack the object against the types you need to handle and away you go. The code you're looking for is something like:

```
if (parent is MovieClip) {...something...}
```